# Firebase authentication error getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:

Tags: java, android

I'm setting up firebase authentication but I'm getting this error

```
getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@e1debed
```

My mobile is note 3 with `android 5.0`, playstore version is `11.0.20-all`, google play services version is `12.8.74`

And here is my dependencies:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

I have read all posts in stackoverflow but I didn't find answers that could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

1. Add this to **end** of the app level **build.gradle**

> `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

2. Add this to project level **build.gradle**

> ```
> dependencies {
> .....
> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
>
> }
> ```

3. Rebuild project again.

Comment: Same error `getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@24c9aa96` I tried downgrading before didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Update google-services to recent version and rebuild project.

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'


}
```

Comment: I have this issue today. It still work fine yesterday. Now, ios work but android emulator doesn't work. I didn't test android real device yet.

I tried everything but can't make it work. Every firebase function hang and console log only this I/BiChannelGoogleApi(29258): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@6deb1d3